# Pycharm and multiple projects: why does it add other project as content roots?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm (2021.2.1) and have multiple projects opened in one window (opened with "Attach" option selected).

I've set up content root for each project (each project has one content root). I've set dependencies for each project. Everything worked okay.

But when I re-ran PyCharm I found that it had automatically set extra content root for each project. And now each project was having multiple content roots.

[image: Project source roots: why does it add extra source roots?!]

And in PyCharm Project View some project were not shown at top level, but only at sublevel, that was really annoying (see pic.2).

[image: Project View:]

Why does it happen? And how can I prohibit PyCharm to add extra source roots automatically, i'm already tired to delete it manually.

P.S. When I've just entered `pip3 install pyspark>=3.2.0` in Terminal Window (with virtualenv enabled) it happened again. Oy vey!